# Access method of second base class with super()

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.x, inheritance

Please explain to me the following. If I execute this:

```
class Base1:
    def foo(self):
        print('in Base1.foo')

b1 = Base1()
b1.foo()


class Base2:
    def foo(self):
        print('in Base2.foo')

b2 = Base2()
b2.foo()

class Child1(Base1, Base2):
    def foo(self):
        super(Child1,self).foo()

c1 =  Child1()
c1.foo()

class Child2(Base1, Base2):
    def foo(self):
        super(Base1,self).foo()

c2 =  Child2()
c2.foo()
```

I get this:

```
in Base1.foo
in Base2.foo
in Base1.foo
in Base2.foo
```

I understand the first three lines of the output. But why do I have to give the name of the first base class to `super()` in order to get the method of the second base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mucking with the [*Method Resolution Order*](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), or *MRO*. Python class inheritance hierarchies are *linearised*, given a specific order, according to a system called the [*C3 linearisation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization).

`super()` uses that order to find the *next* attribute (including methods) in that ordering. Given a current instance, and a class, it'll search the order for an attribute **past** the given class. For both `Child*` classes, the MRO lists the `Child*` class first, followed by `Base1` and `Base2`. In your last example you told `super()` to go looking in that MRO starting from the next class after `Base1`, so only `Base2.foo()` remains to be found.

You can ask any class for its MRO by calling the [`class.mro()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.mro):

```
>>> Child2.mro()
[<class '__main__.Child2'>, <class '__main__.Base1'>, <class '__main__.Base2'>, <class 'object'>]
```

`super()` can be used *outside* methods too; you can then easily see what happens when you pick different starting points for the search:

```
>>> super(Child2, Child2()).foo
<bound method Base1.foo of <__main__.Child2 object at 0x10f40ff98>>
>>> super(Base1, Child2()).foo
<bound method Base2.foo of <__main__.Child2 object at 0x10f40ffd0>>
>>> super(Base2, Child2()).foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Comment: I was aware of the the method resolution order, but I didn't know that super() gets the "next" base class in line... thanks